# MySQL remote database server connect failed

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0, mysql-error-2002

I am trying to connect `Cakephp 3.x` remote database server from my local machine.

**But it showing below error**

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host

**My local database configuration in `app.php` is look like -**

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '192.168.1.19',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        'port' => '3306',
        'username' => 'remote_db_user',
        'password' => 'my_password',
        'database' => '********',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
     ],
     /*Other configs*/
]
```

**About the remote server :**

> - `ping 192.168.1.19` is ok for this IP from my PC
> - There is no name server for this `IP` address

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: what about username,password and database ? are they all ok ?

Comment: I think in the host you should only give the IP ie, 192.168.1.19, not the protocol(https), that is specified by the port

Comment: Yes! All credentials are OK. @ManoharKhadka

Comment: I also checked without `'https` But nothing happened @RohitAilani

Comment: I fixed some issue, And updated the question. Current error `Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host` @ManoharKhadka

Comment: try connection using a test file in your webroot directory and do a direct mysql_connect there and check are you able to achieve that and if you are then please post that in the question, so that we can check further the exact issue.

Comment: I already checked, There is another error `PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`, Anyway Thank you for your advice. Maybe there is server issue. I am trying to fix it @RohitAilani

Comment: I solved the problem! There was `IP` and `mysql` user permission problem @RohitAilani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally I solved this problem by following some steps-**

***Step 1 (Edit mysql config file)***

> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Find and changed below line

> bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

**TO**

> bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

***Step 2 (Grant Database permission for User)***

> CREATE USER 'remote_db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remote_db_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

***Step 3 (Restart Apache)***

> sudo service apache2 restart

***Step 4 (Restart mysql)***

> sudo service mysql restart

**And now, I am able connect remote database using `CakePHP 3`**

Answer (score 3):

Please check the firewall rules. for example, if your MySQL running port is 3306 check whether is it open or not. and please check this rule allowed too.

> ufw allow mysql